# Terraform aws cognito user pool

Tags: terraform, amazon-cognito

Ok so I was able to create the script but when I run terraform apply it gives me this error. Any ideas as how I can fix it?
Terraform version= Terraform v0.12.2
provider.aws v2.47.0

Error:
An argument or block definition is required here. To set an argument, use the
equals sign "=" to introduce the argument value. 
This is giving the error for the line below(password_policy.temporary_password_validity_days = 7):

`resource "aws_cognito_user_pool" "admin_cognito_pool" {`
  `name                     = "dummy-pool"`
  `username_attributes      = ["email"]`
  `auto_verified_attributes = ["email"]`
 `admin_create_user_config {`
    `allow_admin_create_user_only = true,`
    `#unused_account_validity_days = 7`
    `password_policy.temporary_password_validity_days = 7`
  `}`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have a specific issue or are you getting an error with what you've tried? Please edit your question to include a [mcve] of where you're up to and use that to explain your problem clearer.

Comment: Hi ydaetskcoR, so I was able to fetch the details of an existing pool using below . I have the existing setting of a user pool in the terraform.tfstate file. I just wanted to create a script using the exact config of the pool in the testate file so I can create a new pool using a script. Needed some input based on that.          provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_cognito_user_pool" "pool" {
    name = "dummypool"
}
resource "aws_cognito_user_pool_client" "client" {
    name = "client"
    user_pool_id = "${aws_cognito_user_pool.pool.id}"
}